# Вертикальный отступ между полями через margin не меняется

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать вертикальный отступ между полями для ввода и текстом, делал через margin но почему-то не меняется отступ, может я не верно указал div

```css
.modalDialog {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20% auto;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">x</a>
    <h2>Тест</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
      <p>Имя</p>
      <input placeholder="Владимир" name="name" type="text">
      <p>Номер</p>
      <input placeholder="+7 777 77 77 777" name="number" type="text">
      <p>Emai.</p>
      <input placeholder="example@mail.com" name="email" type="text">
      <p><input value="Отправить" class="SuperButton" type="submit"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ещё бы css показали бы - вообще был бы класс

Comment: @МаксимЛенский тот вопрос по WordPress - он нерешаемый, на мой взгляд, средствами css. Автор хочет изменить ширину родительского li при ховере в зависимости от ширины дочернего ul. Не бывает ))

Comment: не wordpress, поля статичные, внутри модальной формы, мне нужно отступ между текстом имя и полем для ввода имя, отступ вертикальный.

Comment: CSS приложите свой

Comment: все я приложил css

Comment: @KAGGDesign  можно но будет шляпа не красивая

Comment: @servarez да мы тут с Ленским оффтопик обсуждаем, сорри. Тот ответ удален, там не напишешь))

Comment: может мне поможете как сделать отступ то между именем и полем для ввода, просто я прописываю margin-top для всех инпутов и ничего не меняется, помогите а

Comment: @servarez оберните все ваши инпуты в параграф - и потом зададите нужный наружный отступ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так сделайте - и всё будет как надо ....

здесь я ещё кнопку очистки формы добавил: https://jsfiddle.net/nchjf3or/17/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

.modal input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.modal p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 340px;
}

.modal p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.close {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #cc0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#form">зарегаться</a>

<div id="form" class="modal">
  <a href="#" class="close">x</a>
  <form name="" action="">
    <span>Форма регистрации</span>
    <p><input type="text" name="" placeholder="имя" required></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="" placeholder="фамилия" required></p>
    <p><input type="email" name="" placeholder="email" required></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="" placeholder="пароль" required></p>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="отправить">
  </form>
</div>
```